# Green-Kubo relation for viscosity

Tags: stress-strain, viscosity

I want to compute the shear viscosity of a system using Green-Kubo relation. I have the full stress-tensor evolution $P_{ij}(t)$ and the system is isotropic so I can write

$$ \eta = \frac{V}{k_B T} \int_0^\infty < P_{xy}(0) \cdot P_{xy}(t') > \cdot dt'  $$

I thought that $< P_{ij}(0) \cdot P_{ij}(t) >$ was the time autocorrelation function for the non-diagonal components of the stress tensor, but it cannot be because acf is normalized and for something with units it not make any sense to me... I thought in autocovariance, but I don't know because I check the value with another method and both values not match... or maybe I'm doing something wrong with autocovariance...

However, I would like to know an explicit expression for $< P_{ij}(0) \cdot P_{ij}(t) >$ and the stadistical name of this magnitude, not the physics name "time autocorrelation function" because it is a little confuse and I cannot fully understand this formula

Answer (score 1):

The autocorrelation function doesn't need to be normalized, see the [definition here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation). It also *must* have units of $[P^2]$, or $N^2\cdot m^{-4}$ since $\eta$ has to have units of $N\cdot s\cdot m^{-2} $.

To actually calculate this, I'd try using [scipy's correlate function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html) (linked) and check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643699/how-can-i-use-numpy-correlate-to-do-autocorrelation) for how to calculate the autocorrelation with it.

From the second answer in the link above,

> Auto-correlation comes in two versions: statistical and convolution. They both do the same, except for a little detail: The statistical version is normalized to be on the interval [-1,1].

So it appears the statistical acf differs from the physical one by normalization.

Comment: So, when I compute the acf I have to use stress-tensor in Pa? Maybe I'm not doing this right, but to compute this acf I'm trying to use python an the function ```from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf``` (https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html), this acf is always in between 0 and 1, independence of the units, that's why I talk about normalization ...

Comment: I adjusted my answer to address this comment

Comment: @user239504, does my response answer your question? If so consider voting it up and marking it as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at [this link](https://nanohub.org/resources/7581/download/Martini_L9_DynamicProperties.pdf), it provides a numerical example.

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/431556)

Comment: Thank you, it's done